# Observing RSSI change on CLBeacon

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibeacon

My purpose is to record the change on RSSI a single beacon.
Firstly i monitor the region of a static UUID, then select the beacon of interest.
So i ended up with one single CLBeacon object. The problem is that, the RSSI value does not change on this object (not surprisingly), i have to find the interest beacon from "..didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons" each time i need the new RSSI value.

I already tried to use always the pointed object, but i hope there is a convention for that.

I hope my statement is clear, is there a known solution for that ?

Comment: Can you link to code?

Comment: You are thinking correctly. You will receive the updated RSSI value only in the delegate method. Just update the property (either the selected beacon object or directly the RSSI value for selected beacon) in and monitor the value of that variable periodically in a timer method.

Comment: The thing is, i pass the CLBeacon object on a segue (beaconWeWantToRecord passed on segue prepare). I try to think an efficient way to that, if not better use the delegated method :)
Thanks for the comments

http://pastebin.com/TWU5s6dQ

Comment: You need your active view controller to be your location delegate so it can receive the updates or you need to forward the information from your actual delegate to the active view controller